# Many-to-Many Relations using non-"id" Primary Key in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine

So I'd like to create two entities and make a many-to-many reference. I would love to make this association using a string primary key on one table. This seems to be really hard, at least it took me pretty much time trying without any results yet.

This is my approach:

First entity:

```
namespace Project\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $Id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="Users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_user",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName="Id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Role_Name", referencedColumnName="Name")}
     * )
     */
    private $Roles;
}
```

And the second:

```
namespace Project\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Role")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=256)
     */
    private $Name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_user",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Role_Name", referencedColumnName="Name")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName="Id")}
     * )
     */
    private $Users;
}
```

Output of `./app/console doctrine:schema:validate`:

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Project\AdminBundle\Entity\User' mapping is invalid:
* The referenced column name 'Id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'Project\AdminBundle\Entity\User'.
* The referenced column name 'Id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'Project\AdminBundle\Entity\Role'.
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Attention upper/lowercase! Doctrine generates its columns as lowercase per default. This solves the issue:

```
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="User_Id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="Role_Name", referencedColumnName="name")}
```

This it over-complicated; it's enough to put this into the `Role` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="Roles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_user", referencedColumnName="name")
 */
private $Users;
```

I only thought about this when writing the question.. what a good method to think about the problem again from scratch.

Cheers